# Nesting templates as part of a table is mysteriously eating a word in MediaWiki

Tags: templates, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

When I use templates as individual lines in a table, it mostly seems to work perfectly, except for one spot where it keeps eating the first word of the second column, and I don't know why.

Background: I have a small MediaWiki, just large enough to need several navigation lists, which I then want to group together at the bottom of pages as a sitemap.

So on an individual page I use the template Template:Core_Links

```
'''[[Main Page]]''' || [[FAQ]] | [[Groups]] | [[Other Stuff]]
```

I have identically formatted Region_Links, Leadership_Links, etc. to use as headers on the relevant pages.

Then I have Template:Sitewide_Links, which does this:

```
{| class="wikitable"
|+ '''Site at a Glance'''
!Core pages
!More information
|-
|  {{Core Links}}
|-
|  {{Leadership Links}}
|-
|  {{Unfinished Links}}
|-
|  {{Good to Know Links}}
|-
|  '''Webmaster'''  ||  {{Webmaster}}
|}
```

I get a nice table, with the double-pipe in the smaller templates acting as a column delimiter. It works great.

Except on the Template:Unfinished_Links in the middle there. I haven't actually linked the words following the double-pipe, which could be the problem.

Here's the code of Template:Unfinished_Links

```
'''[[Bad Portal]]''' || Add | Links | Like | This
```

And when it is included as itself, all of those words show up like they're supposed to.

But when it's included as part of the Sitewide table template, that line looks like... (assume the double-pipe is a column divider)

```
'''[[Bad Portal]]''' || Links | Like | This
```

It ate the word "Add" and the following pipe.  I tried changing it to different words, looked for extra spaces, any tiny syntax error that would cause this.

The only difference I can see is that they are not links yet, but nothing in what I've read of table markup suggests that should make a difference.

I know this is, in general, a brittle solution.  The answer could be "just import Navbox from Wikipedia." However I'm pretty new at this and I'm daunted by all the potential debugging and digging into css or javascript that might entail. If I can make this or something similar work Good Enough, I'd like to.

Comment: So, you want to show a literal pipe character? Have you tried something like `'''[[Bad Portal]]''' || Add <nowiki>|</nowiki> Links <nowiki>|</nowiki> Like <nowiki>|</nowiki> This`?

Comment: I have not tested that, but I think adding <nowiki> would do it. The point of my question is that, except in the very specific case where the first thing after the double-pipe is a normal word instead of a link, my syntax works perfectly. So why would a non-link respond by eating the first unit of text?

Comment: I know that's the only difference because I changed it to [[Add]] (linked the word) and it reappeared.  This seems like a weird and concerning difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, pipes have a meaning in the table syntax. Within a cell, the first pipe and what precedes it is assumed to be a set of [cell attributes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#Attributes_on_cells), like `| style="text-align:right;" | 500.00` instead of a mere `| 500.00`.

There is no proper way to (ab)use the pipe within a table, but if you really must then you could try and play with the [`{{!}}` magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Other) etc.

Comment: In short, the thing I am doing ought not be done. Overloading the visual markup of the small bar to make it also work as part of table markup is a non-starter, and I lucked out that it worked as well as it did.